# find canonical link using Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am trying to use Simple HTML Dom to find any references to the canonical link on the website. I have used the same process as with finding meta descriptions but it does not work.

```
$html->find('head link[rel=canonical]', 0)->content
```

Comment: What is your input, what is the output, what are you expecting?

Comment: @Andy the canonical link is the `<link>` element in a page `<head>` with attribute `rel=canonical`.

Answer (score 2):

The canonical link looks like this:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26365930/use-simple-html-dom-to-find-cannonical-link" />
```

You need to get the `href`, rather than the content of the node:

```
# get all the link elements with rel="canonical"
$canon = $html->find('head link[rel=canonical]');

# get the href attribute of the link
foreach ($canon as $c) {
    echo $c->href . "\n";
}
```

Running the code on this page, the output is:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26365930/use-simple-html-dom-to-find-cannonical-link
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the help I Alarmed Alien I was looking for content which didn't exist;

`$html->find('head link[rel=canonical]', 0)->href` works just fine